# UWP MediaElement Closed Caption Support

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, mediaelement

I'm writing an Windows 10 UWP app (NOT WPF or Sliverlight) which can play media files.

To do so, I am using [MediaElement Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx) to implement a player.

The problem is that I cannot find **what kinds of caption are supported by MediaElement**(ME). I could not find any website that explains it.

Is there any web page that has information about exact scope of internal/external captions that ME supports?

---

### My Attempts

To know internal closed caption support, I tried playing some .mkv files that include various closed captions.
The result is here:

1. Works well:   UTF-8 Plain Text, ASS Format
2. Doesn't work: VobSub, Timed Text(Codec ID:tx3g), PGS

Also, for external closed caption files (.srt, .ass, .smi for example), I could check that .srt files are supported by using TimedTextSource but .smi files are not. (From VideoPlayback project in [windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples))

---

I wish there exists a page about this information.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you seen the [Microsoft VideoPlayer sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/93bdfb92b3da76f2e49c959807fc5643bf0940c9/Samples/VideoPlayback)?

Comment: Yes, this is same project that I have tried for external CC (above 'VideoPlayback project in windows-universal-samples'), but thank you for your kindness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Microsoft Media Player Framework I think is the most complete media player for UWP apps supports advanced scenarios and obviously supports closed captions and the best thing is open source.

https://playerframework.codeplex.com

Comment: Thank you for new possibility :) I should investigate this project.

Comment: I read the website. There (https://playerframework.codeplex.com/discussions/638537) I could find the exact information. As a conclusion, Player Framework (PF) only supports out-of-band WebVTT/TTML. Embedded/in-band captions are not supported by PF. Since I have to support as many kinds of captions as possible, I think I should use the MediaElement for now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TimedTextSource` to support closed-captioning.
See Scenario 4 in [Microsoft's VideoPlayback sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/VideoPlayback/cs/Scenario4_DisplayingOutOfBandClosedCaptions.xaml.cs). You have to set the `TimedTextSource` as an `ExternalTimedTextSources` in the `MediaSource`.